# Is every null set a subset of an uncountable null set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In $\mathbb{R} ^{n}$, regarding the Lebesgue measure, is every null set a subset of an uncountable null set?

And is there a simple proof for that?

Comment: By "Null Set" do you mean a set of measure 0? Also, what is your ambient space? $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, by null set i mean measure 0. The ambient space is R^n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cantor set is  an uncountable null set. If $E$ is any null set then $E \subset E \cup C$ and $E \cup C$ is an uncountbale null set.

Comment: This is for $\mathbb R$ and it is much easier to find uncountable null sets in higher dimensional Euclidean spaces: look at the axes.